# 3D Perspective Projection doesn't look right

Tags: 3d, projection, cube, perspective

I have been using the 3D perspective projection formula:

```
sx = wx*scale/wz
sy = wy*scale/wz
```

It projects things sort-of alright, but for example a cube looks more like a rectangular prism and is really stretched out.

It looks like this:

[image]

I have done research on it and looked at the other pages on it on stackoverflow, but I don't really understand why it is stretching it out.

I've also tried other alternatives like dividing the z-value by 2 or 4, or some arbitrary value to make it look more cube-ish but for more complex objects it doesn't really do the trick.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: have you read http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/3D_projection?

Comment: What are the 8 world coordinates of the cube? And what did you get as the screen coordinates?

Comment: @SteveH Yes I have read that. I got the formula from another website a while back. I just decided to start doing 3D stuff again.

Comment: @Alex I didn't do a full cube, just three faces.
The coordinates of the cube are:
    front = (5,5,5),(0,5,5),(0,10,5),(5,10,5),(5,5,5)
    right = (5,5,5),(5,5,10),(5,10,10),(5,10,5),(5,5,5)
    left = (0,5,5),(0,5,10),(0,10,10),(0,10,5),(0,5,5)

Comment: I think it's just too close to the camera and 1/z is very different for small different z's. Move it farther away.

Answer (score 2):

Your projection looks like an extreme wide-angle view.  It's a "correct" perspective projection - your formula is the right one, but the key is in the `scale` variable/constant.

The value for `scale` is generally

```
screen_width_in_pixels * focal_length
```

where `focal_length` is the ratio of the distance from the viewer's eyes from the screen, to the width of the screen.  Of course you can't control how close someone sits in front of their monitor, so you guess. 1.0 - 1.5 is generally a good range.

When you change that value to something less wide-angle, a side-effect will be that the 'camera' will 'zoom in' on your object, and probably fill up the screen.  So you will need to compensate by moving the object further away from the camera.

There is (of course) a nice long [Wikipedia article on the subject](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/3D_projection).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I tried you're method for scaling, but it still looks stretched out. It looks about the same as before.

Any ideas on what else I could change to stop it stretching?

Comment: check your coordinates.  Are those actually the faces of a cube?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same 'issue' when trying to render a box on the html5's canvas. What made the stretched box look 'normal' for me was to set the **z** value of the camera's position [image: a Camera Formula] to -250 instead of -50 that I used. Then, depending on what formula you use for calculating the x,y coordinates, you can adjust either the viewer's z position (ez)

[image: a Viewer]

or the distance from the recording surface to the entrance pupil (rz) to zoom onto your object.

[image: a formula]

I know that the question was asked half a year ago but since I din't find any answers that helped me I decided to share my own experience. Hopefully it helps someone.